# Eclispe4: Get reference to a Part

Tags: eclipse-rcp

so I defined a `Part` in my e4 RCP application (inside `Application.e4xmi`) and assigned it an `ID`. How can I get a reference to this `Part` in code. I need a reference to be able to execute a methode on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject the model service `EModelService` and the application `MApplication` and call

```java
modelService.find(id, application);
```

You can use other parts instead of `MApplication` but the application should always work.

Comment: Thank you, this is a very convenient way to get the Part! One problem remains for me: I want to access an object that is instanciated in the @PostConstruct methode of my Part (It is declared as a global variable and I want to retrieve it with a getter) but it is always null. Even after I let the application load it once.

Comment: That sounds like a new question and we would probably need to see some code.

Comment: Hehe I thaught so also, and just created it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20245358/eclipse4-unable-to-access-stw-widget-of-a-part-if-part-is-retrieved-with-eparts